# How to fade in the contents of the modal but not the background?

Tags: html, css

Surprisingly, after googling this for a bit I found tons of questions about how to fade the background of a div (not the text), but none of the converse. Please point me to one if you can find it.

I'm looking for a way to fade in the *contents* of a div. For example, I have a modal and if I apply the following rule to it:

```
animation-name: contentfadein;
animation-duration: 1s;

@keyframes contentfadein {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Then it fades in everything (including the modal background itself).

Rather, I would like to *only* fade in the contents, such that the modal immediately loads and has its white background, but all of the contents of the modal fade in (such as the text, buttons, etc.)

All of the approaches I've tried so far *also* fade in the background, which I am looking to avoid.

The only thing I could think of is to apply this rule on every.. single.. item.. in the modal, but that would result in hundreds of individual rule additions (and also stop working when a new item is added, until that item is "fixed"), which seems inefficient compared to a better way.

Comment: `div.modal > *` includes every single child element. Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: @RickardElimää Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either.. Not sure why but it still includes the background

Comment: `div.modal > *` select direct childs. You need to use `div.modal *` to select all childs. See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. My modal has two panes and if I apply that rule to each of the panes then it fixes it. My apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply rules to [all component inside an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) with css easily. Then you will need to deal with text directly inside your container, you can change the color of your text to transparent.

```css
.container{
  background: red; /* won't fade */
}

.container, .container *{
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

/* This will apply for all content in .container */
.container:hover * {
  opacity: 0;
}

/* OPTIONAL : This will apply for text directly in container */
.container:hover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  I'm text directly in container
  <p>I'm a paragraphe</p>
  <input type='submit' value="I'm a submit button"/>
  <div>
    <p>I'm in a div and a paragraphe</p>
  </div>
</div>
```